# Python Selenium - get specc href value

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, href

i am trying to extract all the href values form the following HTML:

```
<div class="ProductCard">
<div class=ProductCard-image">...</div>
<a class="ProductCard-link ProductCard-content"
target="_self" href="/product/jordan-retro-5- 
mens/D0587600.html"
```

I've tried:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class="ProductCard-link ProductCard-content"][href]')
and 
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="ProductCard-link"]')
```

In each case, I get that elems in an empty list.

If it helps, all the 20+ href are categorized under the same class name:

```
<li class="product-container col">
```

though I've tried the same.

For further insight on the HTML refer to the following link: https://www.footlocker.com/category/brands/jordan.html

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS selector is fine, you just need to loop over it and grab the `href` attributes

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class="ProductCard-link ProductCard-content"][href]')

links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]

print(links)

['https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-aj-1-mid-mens/54724122.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-6-rings-mens/22992106.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-aj-1-mid-mens/54724170.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-true-flight-boys-grade-school/43795121.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-aj-xxxv-mens/Q4227030.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-aj-1-mid-mens/C0978006.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-flight-45-high-ip-mens/C2569001.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-aj-1-low-mens/53558700.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-6-rings-boys-grade-school/23419060.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-true-flight-mens/42964104.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-6-rings-mens/22992008.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-6-rings-mens/22992060.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-zion-1-mens/A3130002.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-retro-6-boys-preschool/84666106.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-pro-strong-mens/C8418101.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-6-rings-boys-grade-school/23419107.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-6-rings-mens/D5077105.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-aj-1-mid-se-boys-toddler/D2193001.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-6-rings-girls-grade-school/23399002.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-why-not-zero-4-mens/D1156301.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-ma2-mens/V8122101.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-true-flight-boys-toddler/43797121.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-true-flight-boys-preschool/43796121.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-aj-11-comfort-low-boys-grade-school/D0851005.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-zion-1-boys-grade-school/A3131002.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-6-rings-girls-preschool/23431002.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-flight-45-high-mens/H0243600.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-pro-strong-boys-grade-school/C7911101.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-pro-strong-boys-toddler/C7910101.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-aj-11-low-cmft-mens/M0844005.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-aj-1-mid-boys-grade-school/H0200100.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-why-not-zero-4-mens/Q4230001.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-max-200-mens/D6105006.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-flight-45-high-ip-mens/H0560100.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-6-rings-boys-preschool/23432107.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-flight-45-high-ip-mens/C2571100.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-zoom-92-mens/K9183001.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-zoom-92-mens/K9183103.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-pro-strong-boys-preschool/C7909101.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-gfx-fleece-hoodie-mens/V2366412.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-max-aura-2-boys-grade-school/N8094100.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-retro-5-graphic-fleece-pullover-mens/D5261010.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-6-rings-boys-toddler/23420008.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-flare-boys-preschool/7849001.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-retro-8-girls-grade-school/80528006.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-jumpman-air-shorts-mens/V3098412.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-mj-jumpman-diamond-9-shorts-mens/V6022068.html', 'https://www.footlocker.com/product/jordan-zoom-92-mens/K9183101.html']
```

Comment: This solution is also looking ok, mine would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different css locator.
Also, you should find parent elements and put them to the list.

After that - iterate through the list and get `href` attribute value.

```
cards = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".product-container>.ProductCard")
links = []
for card in cards:
    link = card.find_element_by_css_selector(".ProductCard-link.ProductCard-content").get_attribute("href")
    links.append(link)
```